# Rewrite Rule Does Not Behaves As Expected

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use PHP mod_rewrite to alter some URLs.

As a test, in my .htaccess I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ index.php?test=$1
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?test=$1
```

In my index.php file I have simply

```
<?php print_r($_GET) ?>
```

What I would like to happen is that when either mysite.com/test or mysite.com/test/ is in the browser address bar, the PHP $_GET['test'] variable has the value 'test' in it.

The commented line works fine with mysite.com/test/ but seems to do nothing with mysite.com/test

The second line (the uncommented one) results in a value of 'index.php' for $_GET['test'] when viewing mysite.com/test and doesn't do anything with mysite.com/test/

Is there anything I'm overlooking here that will allow me to get the desired results?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?test=$1
```

Note for `*?` quantifier, which declares `*` to be `ungreedy`

http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#Greedy

Comment: Thanks so much.  A quick test gets me the results I needed.